# Strange selection behavior of TreeView nodes

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, treeview

Clicking on any of the nodes of my `TreeView` doesn't select it. I need to click on a small rectangular area to the left of the node (shown red in the image) to select it. Also, selecting a node this way means the entire sub-tree with all of the child nodes will be selected at once. Not sure what's going on.

[image]

Here is my XAML:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding FirstGeneration}">
    <TreeView.Resources>         
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:AccountNodeVM}">
        <TreeViewItem Header ="{Binding Name}" />
      </DataTemplate>  

      <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:CategoryNodeVM}" ItemsSource="{Binding SubCategories}">
        <TreeViewItem  Header="{Binding Name}" ItemsSource="{Binding Accounts}" />
      </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>

    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
      </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
  </TreeView>
```

`FirstGeneration`, `SubCategories`, `Accounts` are all defined in my ViewModel. I have tried using `TextBlock` instead of `TreeViewItem` in my `HierarchicalDataTemplate` as well without any gain. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out. `TreeView` appears to create a `TreeViewItem` for each node by itself, so when creating your `HierarchicalDataTemplate`, you do not need to embed `TreeViewItem` inside it, else WPF will wrap your `TreeViewItem` inside its own `TreeViewItem`, thereby confusing the selection mechanism. Simply put a `TextBlock` (or maybe `StackPanel` or some other container if you have complex node structure) in your `HierarchicalDataTemplate` and let WPF do the work of node creation. Hope this helps someone else.